# Notification center in Golang

Tags: go, nsnotificationcenter

I have an iOS development background and I am studying the Go language.
I would like to know if there is something in Go similar to NSNotificationCenter in iOS?

So say I want to update a couple of objects that I don't have direct access to. Is there an easy way to send notification to them?
Or there is no such pattern and I need to do it in different way?

P.S. More info about NSNotificationCenter: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like https://github.com/asaskevich/EventBus

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try!